# Saltwater Desalinization

Tags: physical-chemistry

If a bucket of seawater is put into a centrifuge, would the spinning force be enough to move the salt in the solution toward the outer wall of that centrifuge?

Answer (score 2):

This will not work. Centrifugation will only separate heterogeneous mixtures by density. For example, when centrifuging blood, the cells and platelets will separate to the bottom of the tube because they are not in solution. Depending on the lipid concentration in the plasma, a lipid layer may phase separate (not in solution) and move to the top.

The salt in sea water is dissolved in solution. It will not separate. Even if the centrifugation would produce a concentration gradient across the solution, diffusion would counteract that gradient.

Comment: Thank you Ben. Excellent and simple explanation. And as I expected. :-(

Comment: Sorry. Desalinization is done commercially by distillation or reverse osmosis.